# Given principal bundle $P_O(E)\to E$ with fibration $O_n\to P_O(E)\to X$, there is an exact sequence...

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, sheaf-cohomology

Consider $E$ a rank $n$ real vector bundle over $X$. Let $P_O(E)$ be the orthonormal frames of $E$. This is a principal bundle $P_O(E)\to X$ with $O(n)$ action. Thus there is $i:O(n)\to P_O(E),\pi:P_O(E)\to X$ where $i$ is any inclusion fiber map.

"there is an exact sequence, $0\to H^0(X,Z_2)\to H^0(P_O(E),Z_2)\to H^0(O(n),Z_2)\to H^1(X,Z_2)$."

$\textbf{Q:}$ Where is this Cech cohomology exact sequence coming from? My guess is that first map is given by pulling back $0-$th cocycle from $X$ to $P_O(E)$. The second map is given by inclusion. My guess is that this cohomology level map is insensitive to homotopy. Thus I take any fiber inclusion will induce the second map. Is this correct? Any reference indicating Cech cohomology invariant under homotopy of maps?

$\textbf{Q':}$ Where is last map coming from(i.e. $H^0(O(n),Z_2)\to H^1(X,Z_2)$)? Normally, to induce long exact sequence of sheaves of abelian groups, one needs short exact sequence of 3 sheaves of abelian groups. My guess is that one take the inclusion map's cocycle by noting that fiber is closed in $P_O(E)$. Then one can try to extend it globally to $P_O(E)$ and then taking coboundary operator produces an element in $H^1(P_O(E),Z_2)$ but this element may not descend to $H^1(X,Z_2)$.

Ref. Spin Geometry, Lawson, Chpt 2, (1.2)

Comment: I think that for all sufficiently good spaces (e.g. locally homologically trivial) Chech = Singular (isomorphism is functorial of course). (Usually for such bundles people tend to restrict to the case of the cellular $X$). From that, we can forget about Chech cohomology and use singular cohomology. You can obtain all that from Serre spectral sequence of fibration $O(n)\to P(O) \to X.$ I think that answers all the questions about homotopical invariance and the nature of this exact sequence.

Comment: I think that your geometric arguments are valid as well. First two maps are just the maps induced by the structure maps of the fibration. The last map comes from the same argument as connecting homomorphism in the corresponding sequence of homotopy groups. To make a formal identification you just apply Poincare/Hurewitz theorem.